# Visual Studio 2015 crashes when working with Javascript files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio

I have a project using angularjs and every time I open a js file, it crashes after a while. I noticed that it happens on the project that uses the _references.js.

Here is what the windows log shows me:

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: exception code c0000005, exception address 27F17075
Stack:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS.Engine.IAuthorFileAuthoring.GetStructure()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS.Engine.Proxy.AuthorFileAuthoringProxy.<GetStructure>b__20_0()
   at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(System.Func`1<System.Object>, System.Func`2<System.Exception,Boolean>, System.Func`2<System.Exception,System.Object>)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS.Shared.ExceptionFilter.Guard(System.Func`1<System.Object>, System.Func`2<System.Exception,Boolean>, System.Func`2<System.Exception,System.Object>)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS.Engine.ServiceCore+GuardRecord.Guard()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS.Engine.ServiceCore.Guard[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] (System.Func`1<System.__Canon>, System.Func`1<System.__Canon>)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS.Engine.Proxy.Proxy`1[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]].GuardAndProxy[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](System.Func`1<System.__Canon>, System.Func`1<System.__Canon>, System.Func`2<System.__Canon,System.__Canon>)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS.Engine.Proxy.AuthorFileAuthoringProxy.GetStructure()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS.Engine.FileAuthoringProxy.GetStructure(Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS.Engine.IScriptContext)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS.NavigationBar.GetScriptLexicalStructureTask.Run()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS.Engine.SingleThreadTask.<Execute>b__24_0()
   at GuardMethodClass.GuardMethod(System.Func`1<System.Object>, System.Func`2<System.Exception,Boolean>, System.Func`2<System.Exception,System.Object>)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS.Shared.ExceptionFilter.Guard(System.Func`1<System.Object>, System.Func`2<System.Exception,Boolean>, System.Func`2<System.Exception,System.Object>)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS.Engine.SingleThreadTask.Execute()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.JSLS.Engine.SingleThreadScheduler.WorkerThreadStart()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Is someone having the same problem? Or know how to fix it?

I sent this bug to Microsoft either: 
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1749105/visual-studio-2015-crashes-when-working-with-javascript-files

Thanks

Comment: Works fine for me. Any extensions installed that could be doing it? Also make sure you've installed any VS2015 related windows updates

Comment: Thanks @dman2306
I use these extensions: 
Chutzpah - for jasmine tests
NUnit - for unit tests and
PostSharp

My pc is updated but is using windows 8.1. Is there a problem?

Comment: I've been watching the node.js tools for visual studio 2015 project, and someone said that Microsoft is discontinuing JSLS, which loads into intellisense much more slowly. Instead, the Microsoft node.js tools team said something like TypeScript replacing JSLS